# Accuracy of machine learning models

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I started learning ML and I have some problems with evaluating / finding the accuracy of regression and classification models.
Till now I used `.score()` in both cases but people told me that Its not the accuracy.
Then I tried to use this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

var_train, var_test, res_train, res_test = train_test_split(variables, results, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 4)

regression = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regression.fit(var_train, res_train)

input_values = [14, 2]

prediction = regression.predict([input_values])
accuracy_regression = mean_squared_error(var_test, prediction)
```

But I always get this error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 1]
```

I have looked all over the udemy and youtube, and a lot of people are calculating accuracy like `.score()`. Then I looked all over `scikit-learn` website and  stackoverflow and I saw the other solution with metrics but I keep getting the same error.
What am I doing wrong?

More about the problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56622349/accuracy-of-multivariate-classification-and-regression-models-with-scikit-learn

Comment: What is the line that returns error?

Comment: The last line : `accuracy_regression = mean_squared_error(var_test, prediction)`

Im trying to find a way to see accuracy / evaluation / score of my regression model. 
For example , your model is 89.53% accurate. Is that possible to do with regression models?

Comment: Can you check the shape/length of your objects `var_test` and `prediction` ? And if they contain any missing values?

Answer (score 1):

Linear regressions are incompatible with accuracy measures. Accuracy is a metric for ***classification tasks only*** - it represents the percentage of observations that your model was able to classify correctly.

In case of Linear regression instead, you are predicting a **continuous output**. No accuracy can be computed on this. You need other metrics, such as MSE (the one you used), that can be interpreted as "*how distant you are from perfect prediction*". Sometimes statisticians use the **R-squared** metric, which represents the percentage of the dependent variable's variance that your model is able to explain (i.e.: when all your data are on a straight line, the R-squared is = 1).

The fact that you are getting an error at `mean_squared_error()` is suggesting me that your input objects (`input_values` and `var_test`) must have either: different shapes, and/or contain missing values. In particular, you are only feeding two observations as `input_values`: `[14, 2]`. Is `var_test` a vector of length 2 ?

Comment: `var_test` is (2,2). You can check the whole code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56622349/accuracy-of-multivariate-classification-and-regression-models-with-scikit-learn

I managed to make it work, i didnt use `prediction = regression.predict([input_values])`,  I have used `prediction = regression.predict(var_test)`  but i get prediction value [697.5 426. ] and mean_squared_error 2086.625.